# Multi-Stage Build Race Condition With Cache

Tags: docker, buildx

I've used multi-stage Docker builds for quite some time, and I'm fairly familiar with `buildx` as well, but it seems to me that there is a race condition within the builder under certain conditions.

I have been iterating on a little example to reuse cached resources across Docker build stages. My goals:

1. In the first stage (builder), copy over the `package.json`, install dependencies with `npm install` into a cache, then finally copy over the actual source code to be efficient on the cache.
2. In the second stage, copy over `node_modules` from the cache from the first stage, then copy over the actual source code from the first stage.
3. Reuse a shared cache for `node_modules` between both stages.

Here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
# to share default build arg values _across all build stages_, you must declare them _before_ any FROM statement, ie at
# the very beginning of your Dockerfile
ARG CACHE_VERSION=v1
ARG NODE_MODULE_CACHE_ID=com.github.naftulikay.my-repo.node-modules.${CACHE_VERSION}

# --- build stage
FROM node:18-alpine as builder

# declaring the build arg within the stage "imports" the build arg's default value to this build stage
ARG NODE_MODULE_CACHE_ID

# create the workdir
RUN install -d -m 0755 /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# bring in dependencies
COPY ./package.json ./package-lock.json ./

# install dependencies into the cache
RUN echo "*** cache id: ${NODE_MODULE_CACHE_ID}"
RUN --mount=type=cache,sharing=locked,id=${NODE_MODULE_CACHE_ID},target=/usr/src/app/node_modules \
    rm -fr node_modules/* && \
    npm install

# copy source code files
COPY ./index.js ./

# --- runtime stage
FROM node:18-alpine

# declaring the build arg within the stage "imports" the build arg's default value to this build stage
ARG NODE_MODULE_CACHE_ID

# create the workdir
RUN install -d -m 0755 /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# copy dependencies from builder stage into this stage (runtime stage)
# NOTE you absolutely do NOT want the `from` argument, it absolutely does not do what you think it does
RUN echo "*** cache id: ${NODE_MODULE_CACHE_ID}"
RUN --mount=type=cache,sharing=locked,id=${NODE_MODULE_CACHE_ID},target=/builder/node_modules cp -r /builder/node_modules ./

# copy source code from builder stage into this stage (runtime stage)
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/index.js ./

# sanity test
COPY sanity.sh ./
RUN ./sanity.sh --clean

CMD ["index"]
```

As far as other resources, there's nothing really remarkable here at all. My `index.js` simply is `console.log("hello world");`, my `package.json` simply requires `pino`, a logging library, and `sanity.sh` simply tests for directory/file presence in the runtime image.

Since I have a `COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/index.js ./` step in the second stage, I imagine that Docker understands that `builder` must be built first before running the second stage, but my observations indicate that both stages are being built simultaneously, and the second stage does not depend on the first.

I am building my image with the following command:

```bash
docker buildx build --progress plain -t docker-stage-cache-test:latest ./
```

If we look at the output, it seems clear that it is building both the first and second stages *simultaneously*, which is extremely problematic to say the least.

I have uploaded the full output from my build execution [here as a Gist](https://gist.github.com/naftulikay/c41a6d5b710c2bce89c810222453df87), but here are the lines that are interesting:

```
#9 [stage-1 4/8] RUN echo "*** cache id: com.github.naftulikay.my-repo.node-modules.v1"
#9 0.537 *** cache id: com.github.naftulikay.my-repo.node-modules.v1
#9 DONE 0.7s

#10 [builder 5/7] RUN echo "*** cache id: com.github.naftulikay.my-repo.node-modules.v1"
#10 0.555 *** cache id: com.github.naftulikay.my-repo.node-modules.v1
#10 DONE 0.7s

#11 [stage-1 5/8] RUN --mount=type=cache,sharing=locked,id=com.github.naftulikay.my-repo.node-modules.v1,target=/builder/node_modules cp -r /builder/node_modules ./
#11 DONE 0.7s

#12 [builder 6/7] RUN --mount=type=cache,sharing=locked,id=com.github.naftulikay.my-repo.node-modules.v1,target=/usr/src/app/node_modules     rm -fr node_modules/* &&     npm install
```

It's clear here that `stage-1` and `builder` are *interleaving* during build, and trampling over one another. This is in spite of having a `COPY --from=builder` line later on in the second stage, but something is clearly wrong here.

If I reverse the order in the second stage so that `COPY --from=builder` occurs before `RUN --mount`, the build order is respected and the two stages no longer run concurrently.

Is there a distinct way to specify that one stage *must* occur *after* the other?

---

**EDIT**: I have created a repository which reproduces this exact problem at [naftulikay/docker-buildx-race-condition](https://github.com/naftulikay/docker-buildx-race-condition). The repository includes version info, logs, basic tooling to reproduce the bug, and a workaround `Dockerfile` which uses an empty file to force build stage ordering.

I have also reported this bug at [docker/buildx#2067](https://github.com/docker/buildx/issues/2067).

I don't think that it merits creating an answer for this, but in short, it appears that the ordering of `RUN --mount` and `COPY --from=builder` in the second stage determines whether the bug occurs.

When the `RUN` statement occurs before the `COPY --from` statement, the race condition is triggered:

```
RUN --mount=type=cache,sharing=locked,id=${NODE_MODULE_CACHE_ID},target=/builder/node_modules cp -r /builder/node_modules ./

COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/index.js ./
```

Simply reversing the order of the two commands resolves the issue:

```
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/index.js ./

RUN --mount=type=cache,sharing=locked,id=${NODE_MODULE_CACHE_ID},target=/builder/node_modules cp -r /builder/node_modules ./
```

This is less than ideal, but a better workaround is to add a step in the `builder` phase which simply creates an empty file:

```
RUN touch .cookie
```

And then in the second stage, `COPY` this file over before running `RUN --mount`:

```
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/.cookie ./

RUN --mount=type=cache,sharing=locked,id=${NODE_MODULE_CACHE_ID},target=/builder/node_modules cp -r /builder/node_modules ./
```

Comment: As you're seeing, BuildKit's layer-dependency checks work a line at a time; until you reach the `COPY --from=...` line, nothing in the second stage depends on the first, in a way the builder can programmatically extract.  Can you also `COPY --from=...` the `node_modules` tree?

Comment: @DavidMaze so in the past, what I have done is that within a `RUN --mount` step, I will copy `node_modules` to a folder outside of the cache, but then this means that I'm storing the files somewhere else, rather than copying them directly. For instance, I would do `RUN --mount=type=cache,... npm install && cp -r node_modules/ /tmp/`. I figured it would be better to not store them in a separate location, rather to just use the existing cache mount in the second stage to copy directly from there.

Comment: You should be able to `COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/node_modules/ ./node_modules/`.  This doesn't repeat any work and it isn't really an "extra copy", and because of the explicit `COPY --from` option the ordering between stages is explicit.